# Proving if $f(x)$ is an integrable function on $[a,b]$ then $g(x)=f(x-c)$ is integrable on $[a+c,b+c]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-verification

> Prove that if $f(x)$ is an integrable function on $[a,b]$ then $g(x)=f(x-c)$ is integrable on $[a+c,b+c]$.

My attempt:

Since $f$ is integrable then there's a sequence of partitions $(T_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ over $(a,b)$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline S(T_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underline S(T_n)$.

For all $n$ we have $T'_n=\{a+c=x_0'...=x'_n=b+c\}$, and $\Delta x_i=x'_0-c-x'_{i-1}+c=\Delta x'_i$, and $f(x_i)=g(x_i+c)$.

Therefore: $$\begin{align}\displaystyle\int ^b_a f(x)dx=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline S(f,T_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underline S(f,T_n)= 
\\&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline S(g,T'_n)-c=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underline S(g,T'_n)-c =\int ^{b+c}_{a+c} g(x)dx-c\end{align}$$

Comment: Your last line is wrong: the two integrals  should be equal. Why did you put $-c$?

Comment: @Crostul I wasn't sure but maybe to correct for the $+c$ in the range?

Comment: Note that if $y := x-c$ then $y \in [a, b]$ and that $f$ is integrable on $[a, b].$

Comment: @Chou why is $y\in[a,b]$ and not $y\in[a+c,b+c]$?